# set action using method from another class in objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods, action, selector

is it possible to set an action using method from another class?? Is there any example code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

action of a button for example?

programmatically will be something like:

```
[button addTarget:objectX action:@selector(methodImplementedInObjectX:) forControlEvents:UIControlEvent...];
```

this can be written anywhere, in your view controller, inside the view itself , etc as long as you have a reference to the button. ;)

**EDIT**

`performSelector:...` methods makes the receiver perform a method. So, in your case it would be:

```
[objectName performSelector:@selector(methodName:) withObject:nil];
```

because `self` won't perform anything right? the one who is performing something will be `objectName`

Comment: i try to use something like that in [self performSelector:@selector(objectName.methodName:) withObject;nil] it gives an error "Expected ')' before ':' token", but when i add a bracket [self performSelector:@selector([objectName.methodName:}) withObject;nil], the error become 2, to be "Expected ':' before '[' token" and "Method name missing in @selector", what's wrong with this code???